# How to document events (Natspec)?

Tags: documentation, natspec

I am trying to add comments/documents following the Natspec. I didn't understand how to document events emitted inside a function. Is there a standard defined for this? I saw [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/8776) but I didn't understand if they have added a standard for events or not. I was hoping something like this (`emits`):

```
 event TestEvent(address yourAddress);

 /// @emits The caller address
 function dummyFunction() returns (uint256)
    { emit TestEvent(msg.sender); 
      return 1;
 }
```

Comment: I usually use `@notice` or `@dev` to tell the reader that this function emits this event.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this functionality was added by https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/9011

But you use `notice`

```
contract ERC20 {
  /// @notice This event is emitted when a transfer occurs.
  /// @param from The source account.
  /// @param to The destination account.
  /// @param amount The amount.
  /// @dev A test case!
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint amount);
```